# Minecraft "Cauldron" (Custom Item Creation) + iConomy

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-bukkit

I'm aware of [bukkit plugins](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/mech-falsebook-0-87-dev-3-craftbook-for-bukkit-83-ics-cauldrons-gates-minecarts-1000.7227/) that allow you to "combine" items into new items, like the default settings in the linked plugin lets you combine a red flower and a white wool block into a red wool block.

I would like to integrate this into my server, but with increase scaling inefficiency. So you could change a stack of logs into a stack of signs with one click, but not the same number of signs that you would get making them individually. That is to balance the saved time.

However, I would like the option to allow people to use [iConomy credits/cash/currency](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/econ-iconomy-5-0-1-eruanna-1200.40/) to offset that inefficiency if they choose. So then said stack of logs **would** turn into the exact amount of signs that it should make.

**Does such a bukkit plugin exist?**

Comment: No it does not. However, no offense, I think it's a rather silly idea. It's making players do something tedious for the sake of being tedious.

Comment: You must misunderstand my question then. I'm looking to allow people to earn points doing things they'll normally do (like mining) to save time in crafting large amounts of click intensive items (like signs). I don't see how that's tedious at all.

Comment: I think the answer is possibly. You can do that no in 1.8.1, I think. Your question is difficult to understand, so I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a plugin that does this as of yet, remember that the RB for Bukkit 1.0.0 wasn't released that long ago (I as a plugin developer myself, usually wait until one of these comes out until I really start to develop anything)

If you want a plugin that does this - then head over to the [Plugin Requests](http://forums.bukkit.org/forums/plugin-requests.13/) section on the [Bukkit Forums](http://forums.bukkit.org). If you want your request to have a better chance of being noticed - then read the stickied posts.

Hope this helps.